# copy data from one list to another

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq

i have two lists `srsEmps` and `destEmps` from classes

```
List<srsEmployee> srsEmps = db.srsEmployees.ToList();
List<destEmployee> destEmps = db2.destEmployees.ToList();

public class srsEmployee
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmpCode { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Salary { get; set; }
    public Nullable<system.datetime> StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<system.datetime> BOD { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public virtual srsDepartment srsDepartment { get; set; }
}

public class destEmployee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string EmpCode { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Salary { get; set; }
    public Nullable<system.datetime> StartDate { get; set; }
    public Nullable<system.datetime> BOD { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public virtual destDepartment destDepartment { get; set; }
 }
```

**And this is my action and i want change .First method because .First is used to find equivalent element (based on Id) in the orher list and i want to copy all data**

```
       public ActionResult Deploy()
    {
        List<srsEmployee> srsEmps = db.srsEmployees.ToList();
        List<destEmployee> destEmps = db2.destEmployees.ToList();
        db2.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [destEmployees]");
        foreach (var element in destEmps)
        {
            var oldValue = srsEmps.First(t => t.Id == element.Id);
            element.Name = oldValue.Name;
            element.EmpCode = oldValue.EmpCode;
            element.Salary = oldValue.Salary;
            element.StartDate = oldValue.StartDate;
            element.BOD = oldValue.BOD;
            element.DepartmentId = oldValue.DepartmentId;
            element.Active = oldValue.Active;
        }
        foreach (var item in destEmps)
        {
            db2.destEmployees.Add(item);
        }
        db2.SaveChanges();

        return View();
    }
```

i want to copy data from `srsEmps` to `destEmps` using linq
so if i have in `srsEmps = {emp1,emp2,emp3}` i want to copy all those objects to `destEmps`

Comment: It's trivial, so I'm not sure where you're having a problem. What have you tried, what was the result and why didn't that work for you?

Comment: @will i updated the question

Comment: So you want all of the objects in one list? Or you want to overwrite objects in one list with properties from objects in the other list?

Comment: yes i want to copy all objects from list to another

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert a class to another when your properties' names are same, just like your classes.

1) Download the nuget package "Automapper".

2) Create a your converter AutoMapperProfile class by using Profile class of Automapper package.

```
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapperProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<srsEmployee, destEmployee>();
        }
    }
```

3) Define the dependency in Application_Start in Global.asax.

```
Mapper.Initialize(x =>
{
    x.AddProfile<AutoMapperProfile>();
});
```

4) Finally, you can convert list to another list.

```
List<srsEmployee> srsEmps = db.srsEmployees.ToList();

destEmps  = srsEmps.Select(x => Mapper.Map<destEmployee>(x))
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: Have you tried this? Wouldn't you also need a mapper for srsDepartment  
 > destDepartment types?

Comment: @Crowcoder i'm using it. If you want to convert revers, you can add  `CreateMap<destEmployee, srsEmployee>();` into AutoMapperProfile class.

Comment: I mean, did you notice `destDepartment` and `srcDepartment` properties are also different types?

Comment: where i can get Project_Load ?

Comment: @Gehad Sorry, i edited it. It is "Application_Start" if you use asp.net framework.

Comment: @Crowcoder Got it now, only one property is different each other. I didn't try like this. But, i think it works excluding the different property. Not sure.

Comment: @ŞerefCanMuştu how i exclude id property to not copying ?

Comment: @Gehad `CreateMap<Foo, Bar>().ForMember(x => x.Id, opt => opt.Ignore());`